# Выборка из двух таблиц в одну с последующим выводом в WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Привет!У меня есть две таблицы Recipe и Ingredients(Recipe хранит рецепты Ingredients хранит ингредиенты для рецептов).Мне нужно Id ингредиента присвоить Id рецепта, к которому оно принадлежит.

Третья таблица должна иметь вид:

```
1 2
1 4
1 6
```

Слева рецепт а справа ингредиент.
Пользователь имеет возможность самостоятельно добавить рецепт с окна WinForms, но ингредиенты должны уходить в свою таблицу, а рецепты с инструкциями в другую и синхронизоватся в общей таблице (RecipeIngredients).

Как записать из окна WinForms в разные таблицы я знаю, а вот как сделать синхронизацию в третьей не пойму.Мне важен сам алгоритм действий, которого не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы записываете новый рецепт в таблицу рецептов и ингредиенты в таблицу ингредиентов, а в таблицу RecipeIngredients вам нужно записать id данного рецепта и id продуктов, используемых в данном рецепте.Вывод:

```
select `название блюда`, `ингридиент`
from Recipe AS R, Ingredients AS I,RecipeIngredients AS RI
where R.recipe_id = RI.recipe_id
and I.ingredient_id = RI.ingredient_id
```

Comment: Именно так но я не пойму как мне записать к примеру три разных ингредиента но с одним и тем же Id рецепта, а также как потом сделать вывод с это соединительной таблицы в WinForm.

Comment: Так же вы можете уменьшить вашу таблицу, сделав так:
все ингредиенты записывайте в одну строчку с помощью конкатенации, просто записываете значение первого поля, потом к нему добавляете запятую и значение второго поля.
При выводе вы можете разбить эту строчку до запятой и вытащить все ингредиенты по отдельности.
В таблице будет одна строчка вместо трех, выглядит так
1 2,4,6

Comment: Спасибо,посмотрел на код и сразу понял как нужно было делать. Если я добавлю конкатенацию то как я буду осуществлять поиск по ингредиентам?